# How to compare selected items of listbox to those in database and delete the ones that aren't selected

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, listbox

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my code to work. I'm retrieving all of my actor objects from my database, which are the castmembers of a certain movie, using LINQ to SQL. I've checked the output and they're just fine.

Because I had to use a dictionary to show the actors names as a whole, I need to compare whether the selected values of the listbox are the same as the combination of the First- and LastName of the actor.

The first thing I'm doing is going through all the selected items in my listbox. Next, I want to compare them to the First and LastName of the actorsm which I retrieved using LINQ. But it doesn't work like I want it to.

Example: Movie is Pulp Fiction and the Actors related to the movie are Uma Thurman, Samuel L. Jackson and John Travolta. When I run this code I get a total of 3 MessageBoxes with the following output:

- [4, Uma Thurman] Matches Uma Thurman
- [5, Samuel L. Jackson] Matches    Uma Thurman
- [6, John Travolta] Matches Uma Thurman

Though what I really want to achieve is that it breaks out of the loop after finding Uma and then get a messagebox saying:

[5, Samuel L. Jackson] Matches Samuel L. Jackson. and so forth. I want to do this since I want to delete and/or insert actors that are selected/deselected from the movie.

```
var deleteMovieActors = db.MovieActors.Where(mid => mid.Movie_MovieId == MovieId).Select(a => a.Actor);

        foreach (var item in lstbActors.SelectedItems)
        {
            foreach (Actor a in deleteMovieActors)
            {
                if (lstbActors.SelectedItem.ToString().Contains(a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString() + " Matches " + a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName);
                    break;
                } 
            }                        
        }
```

Here's how I create my listbox:

```
private void InitializeListBox()
    {
        var actors = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (var actor in db.Actors.ToList())
        {
            actors.Add(actor.ActorId, actor.FirstName + " " + actor.LastName);
        }

        lstbActors.DataSource = actors.ToList();
        lstbActors.ValueMember = "Key";
        lstbActors.DisplayMember = "Value";
        lstbActors.SelectedIndex = -1;

        // Get Actors by MovieId
        var MAct = from ma in db.MovieActors
                   where ma.Movie_MovieId == MovieId
                   select ma;

        List<Actor> act = new List<Actor>();

        foreach (var ma in MAct)
        {
            act.Add(db.Actors.Where(a => a.ActorId == ma.Actor_ActorId).Single());
        }

        foreach (Actor a in act)
        {
            int index = lstbActors.FindStringExact(a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                lstbActors.SetSelected(index, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located in the condition of the IF statement. The SelectedItem property returns the first occurence over and over in the loop.

```
if (lstbActors.SelectedItem.ToString().Contains(a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.ToString() + " Matches " + a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName);
                break;
            }
```

When I changed the code as following, it works:

```
item.ToString().Contains(a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact matches of First and Last Name use string.Equals() rather than contains because contains return all of the string which contains the specified keyword e.g if you use contains for string "Hello" on strings "Hello" and "Hello World", then it will give you both Hello and Hello World.